# using google font apis

Tags: javascript

I am working on a web application using SVG.

The plan is to use the Google Webfonts APIs to let the user choose their font type and then have their name rendered in SVG. The problem is that when I use the Google APIs to access the fonts, it does not work (reverts back to Serif font). However, when I download the Google fonts and then refer directly in my web application, it works…
Could someone please shed some light on how to get this working for the web applications.

Here is the code so far:

```
js.onclick=function()

    {
        var val=document.getElementById("txt").value
        var newText = svgDoc.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","text");
        newText.setAttribute("id", "txxt")
        newText.setAttribute("x",275);
        newText.setAttribute("y",250);
        newText.setAttribute("font-size","50px");
        newText.setAttribute("fill","olive");
        newText.setAttribute("xlink:href",'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans+Std+Light&subset=latin');
        newText.setAttribute("font-family",'JosefinSansStd-Light');
        var textNode = document.createTextNode(val);
        newText.appendChild(textNode);
        svgRoot.appendChild(newText)
}
```

Comment: Why all the downvotes on this?

Comment: My guess: misspelled title ("Probelm in using google font apis")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically all what Google API's do is same as @font-face in CSS but simplier to load fonts from different font providers. And CSS @font-face can be applied only on text.

Comment: Thanks Maris. We are only using plain text.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to do that the other way around... i.e. Google works on text, not on SVG images, so you need to have raw text for the Google Font to work.

Comment: SVG is not _just images_, they can contain CSS and JavaScript just like HTML does.

Comment: Thanks Sohnee, we are using a text box to get simple text inserted and then transforming it into the chosen font using Google font APIs and then in our web application using JS converting that text into SVG. Any help?